# MVC Application is hanging after the html has been rendered

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have an odd problem and would appreciate any help you can provide.

I have a .NET 4.5 MVC application that I am developing using my local IIS server.
The view that is causing the issue is a very large table that has dynamic columns as well as rows. I'm passing it a view model which includes a list for filtering.
Everything works perfectly here. I load the page, everything is rendered as it should, no problem.

The issue occurs when I try to do a post to apply filtering. The site just hangs, but if I hit 'stop' on the browser, the page will then display exactly how it should, with filtering applied. When I check Task Manager, the IIS Worker Process is sitting between 25-30% and I have to kill it to get normal performance back.

I set a breakpoint just inside the closing body and html tags which is hit on the postback, so the html is all being rendered.

Does anyone know what could cause the server to hang up after the html as been rendered? I find this very odd since I can just hit stop in firefox and the page will be displayed perfectly.

Comment: If you open another browser and load the same page or another on the same application. Is the web app able to process the request? Are there any javascript code running after the page loads in the browser?

Comment: Wow, so it works in IE and Chrome. Definitely must be something with the scripts that are running on page load. I didn't think the IIS Worker Process would care about those scripts since they're client-side. I'll dig into it a bit more and report back.

Comment: Can't figure out the cause for the life of me. Works perfectly in IE8, 9, 10, and Chrome, but hangs in Firefox.
I even commented out ALL scripts and the same thing happened. Going to test it in a dev environment and see if it's something specific to my browser or local IIS server.

Comment: try to clear your browser cache as well to make sure no cached scripts are running just to be sure.

Comment: Alright, I just cleared the cache and it now works in Firefox. I have no idea what the issue was and probably never will. Weird.
Thanks for your help, raymond.